# Timeout exception in ExecuteStoreQuery function of LINQ to ENTITY

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities, timeoutexception

I have an MVC application in this i am using ExecuteStoreQuery to execute the dynamical query for LINQ to entity.

I am getting timeout exeption for large number of recods about 12000  but working fine for small number.

But the same query if i execute by writing the LINQ it is working fine.

I have also added default command timeout=600000 in the connection string but is taking too long to execute the query about 20 to 25 min.

What can i do to execute the query faster as the same result is appearing faster using the LINQ query.

I want to use the ExecuteStoreQuery  as my table name is created dynamically.
eg: "select * from "+tablename;
Then using the entity model and ExecuteStoreQuery  executing the above query and then reading the records.

But taking too long for large number of records.

So,how can i get the large records using ExecuteStoreQuery with faster execution speed.

Comment: Show some code, your SQL query and Linq query and also how do you test their performance. Also use ToTraceString to get real SQL query from the Linq query and compare them.

Comment: Thanks for the response ..I will check using ToTraceString